# Gentelella Unwanted Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, gentelella

I am using the latest version of Chrome,  however, the scroll bar always appear when there is only the a single line content within the main container. How to fix this issue ?

[image]

From here: https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/fixed_sidebar.html

Comment: Paste this to your browser console: `$(".right_col").eq(0).attr("style", "min-height: 923px;");`. Basically try changing `min-height` of `right_col` div from `947px;` to `923px` for example. That is a simple workaround for what is probably a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find and open *build/css/custom.min.css*
2. Find `.right_col{background:#F7F7F7}`
3. Replace with `.right_col{background:#F7F7F7;margin-bottom: -13px}`